# How to use different kotlin library versions in each android module?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines

A project has multiple modules, two of which are named :app and :prefs.

The project build.gradle,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
```

and :app build.gradle,

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3"
...
implementation project(":prefs")
```

work fine. However, the :prefs library requires the latest coroutine features,

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0"
```

but the following error occurs:

```
jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module:
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.1.13.
```

Is it possible to have separate versions of the same dependency ... one in each module?